# VB .NET SQL Delete error 'incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, vb.net-2010

i have problem trying to delete record from my VS 2012 and i'm using sql server 2012, this is my task from my lecturer, and i cant solved it

now this is what i have

```
Private Sub bt_hapus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_hapus.Click
    Try
        Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Delete from tabelpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=" & Me.txt_rkm_mds.Text, Me.SqlConnection1)
        sqlda.Fill(dspasien, "tabelpasien")
        MsgBox("Data telah berhasil dihapus")
        bersih()
        pasif()
        normal()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

any help would be greatly apreciated...

Comment: What is the datatype of the field `No_Rkm_Mds`?

Comment: Then, the error are the missing quotes around the textbox value, but, as I have explained in my answer below, NEVER use string concatenation to build an SQL command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A delete command is executed using an SqlCommand and the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method.

Your code should be

```
Try
    Dim cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Delete from tabelpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=@rkm", Me.SqlConnection1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rkm", Me.txt_rkm_mds.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ....
```

Using a parameterized query you don't have to put quotes around your where values (if the underlying field is any kind of char/varchar/nvarchar type) but, the most important benefit of a parameterized query is the elimination  of a possible [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attack

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten your single quote marks I.E." ' " from around your condition.

Your statement Should be

`Delete From tabelpasien where No_Rkm_Mds='" + Me.txt_rkm_mds.Text + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL SERVER, there shouldn't be a `FROM` in the statement.

```
Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("DELETE tabelpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=" & Me.txt_rkm_mds.Text, Me.SqlConnection1)
```

If `No_Rkm_Mds` is a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`, etc..., the value must be wrapped in `'`s.

```
Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("DELETE tabelpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=`" & Me.txt_rkm_mds.Text & "`", Me.SqlConnection1)
```

Finally, you should consider using SQL Parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: i get 'the connection's current state is closed' what must i do

Comment: `Me.SqlConnection1.Open()` before the `Fill` and `Me.SqlConnection1.Close()` after.